# Is it possible to add more than one field to Meta in Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I´m trying to add a unique together to my model, in which I have assigned permissions for backend roles.
My model is like this:

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    order=models.ForeignKey('Order',related_name='orders',on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Order')
    component=models.ForeignKey('Component', related_name='order_component',on_delete=models.RESTRICT,verbose_name='Component')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('order', 'component')
        permissions = (("detail_list", "detail_list"),)
```

When I try to save, it just keep me saying this:

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

I guess I could add permissions in a latter Model, but just for curiosity, anybody please could tell me if that´s the best approach, or if there is somethig I am missing?
Cheers

Comment: Probably you have an indentation problem. Your problem is not with "unique_together". Be sure that you have the same indentation space for all your lines and that you are using tab or commas everywhere. And not a combination on some lines of code

Comment: Indentation is correct, 4 spaced, same on ut and permissions. Meta also well indented. When  IndentationError, it points to last parentheses of permissions line in console, but next line is def __str__ and it´s well indented too ¿O..o?

Comment: Please provide the file on pastebin

Comment: I dont have access to log files, and sources are manually obfuscated for posting here due to client requirements. Áll relevant info has been exposed. guess best approach is declaring permissions in further models, as I said; that should do the trick, even though it´s not the smartest way.